# Silverlight Bing Map with bindable amount of MapItemsControl

Tags: c#, silverlight, bing-maps

Is it possible to add something like ItemsSource to the Bing Map control to bind the MapItemsControls to a ObservableCollection? Actually I want to put different pushpin-styles on a map easily.

Comment: I dont know about the Bing map, but you can definatly  do this with the ESRI silverlight/wpf map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you would like to have a collection of MapItemControls added to a map - and this collection has to be bind-able - created dynamically?

I had a similar issue before. The solution for me was to create a new MapLayer and expose two-dimensional collection of items as DependencyProperty.

Here is a suggested approach:

```
public class SpecialLayer : MapLayer
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSource ... 
    OnPropertyChanged(...) 
    {
        var layer = sender as SpecialLayer;
        foreach(Object in Routes){
            layer.Add(new Pushpin(...));
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote a [short post about it](http://hoonzis.blogspot.com/2012/01/bind-able-layer-for-bing-maps.html). You can check it to get some details.

Honza

Comment: Thank you. Finally I ended up with a ViewModel similar to yours. But I binded the MapLayer Itemssource to an Collection of PushPins, which is updated by the ViewModel, when the sources are changed. In this case, seemed to be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that and pretty much anything you want with layers.

There is all kind of examples available on official site:
http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/